# What's the Recommended Way of Visualizing Data in Windows SQL Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-sql-reporting

I am investigating Azure for a potential project, and one of its aspects is visualizing data captured and stored in Windows Azure Sql Databases.

"Visualization" is a quality that is mentioned in several articles that and I've read and searches that I have made, but I cannot find any good guidance on how to exactly do this.

Here is an article that mentions Hadoop and Storm via HDInsight:
http://www.informationweek.com/big-data/big-data-analytics/microsoft-brings-storm-stream-analysis-to-hadoop/d/d-id/1316686

It features this image:
http://www.informationweek.com/big-data/big-data-analytics/microsoft-brings-storm-stream-analysis-to-hadoop/d/d-id/1316686?image_number=1

As you can see, there is a "presentation and action" component (far right).  It suggests Excel -- which makes the most sense at this point -- and custom dashboards, etc.

Before suggesting Excel (the "best" answer at this point based on my efforts), I wanted to pose the question here to see if there is something better/obvious that I am overlooking.

Comment: It would be incredibly helpful to know why this question is being down-voted. If you can, please provide feedback so that I can contribute more value to this community.  Thank you.

Comment: It's being down-voted not becaus it's a bad question per say, but it's not a great question for SO. Once you start actually developing a solution and run into a specific issue, that's when you ask. This is to open ended and broad. That being said, the easiest is probably to use Reporting Services or Excel. Introducing Hadoop adds a whole other layer of complexity.

Comment: Thanks @ola-ekdahl.  That is good to know.  These types of questions are then better asked on MSDN forums.   Such a shame... I was almost up to the coveted 15 points of rep. :P

Answer (score 0):

Based on answers provided on MSDN Forums, the best way of viewing Azure Sql Data is by using Excel, or connecting to the source via Sql Server Reporting Services:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1950/how-to-connect-to-sql-azure-using-sql-server-reporting-services-2008-r2/